# How to kill a runaway cat?

Tags: shell, terminal, kill, cat, tcsh

Many times I accidentally run the `cat` command on files that have contents up to few thousand lines.

I try to kill the `cat` command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but both only take effect after the total output of `cat` is displayed in the terminal, so I have to wait till `cat` gets completely executed.

Is there a better solution that avoids waiting? Because sometimes the files are up to size of 100MBs, and it gets irritating to wait for it.

I am using `tcsh`.

Comment: Using commands like more, less, tail, head may be an interesting alternative to cat. (of course this is not an answer...)

Comment: that's correct @tonioc but its like torture when I use `cat` for very big files.. have to wait for few minutes.

Comment: @Braiam I'm adding back the `tcsh` tag because [OP's having problems with tcsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176917/how-to-kill-cat#comment292629_176932).

Comment: OP asked "Is there a better solution that avoids waiting?", to which I answer: Try using the "more" command instead of "cat". The "cat" command should never be used on large files for exactly the reason that you are seeing. I recognize that this does not answer the *other* question, "How to kill a runaway cat?"

Comment: What I usually do is first check the number of lines using `wc -l` in the file and then use `less` to go through it page-wise.

Comment: That was the greatest question title I've ever read. Until I saw that the question's link was for UL, I thought you needed help killing an absconding feline.

Comment: *Does double-take at sidebar question from another SE site* *Is very relieved to see "UL" logo next to question*. Nevermind, carry on. (usually, it's Arquade that has the looks-very-wrong-out-of-context question titles)

Comment: I love the double-entendre of the title!

Comment: Try ^S to stop output to your terminal, then ^C to kill it.

Comment: `Ctrl + S` is not working.. I am working on `tcsh`

Comment: I would try the `curiosity` command...

Comment: `alias curiosity='sudo killall cat'`

Comment: @cas You missed the `-9`

Comment: [Related.](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8681/354511#8682 "There’s no point in running.  ")

Comment: @Lenz you have probably not been around too long. "How to kill the parents, leaving the children alive?" (unix.se); "How to get away with murder?" (rpg.se). Unfortunately I can't find them now.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If the file(s) in question contain lots of data, sending the signal can actually get to `cat` before it finishes. What you really observe is the finite speed of your terminal - `cat` sends the data to the terminal and it takes some time for the terminal to display all of it.

Remember that it usually has to redraw the whole output window for each line of output (i.e. move the contents of the window one line up and print the next line at the bottom). While there are techniques and algorithms to make this faster than if it was done the straightforward way, it still takes some time.

Thus, if you want to get rid of the output as quickly as possible, **hide the terminal window**, because then (usually) no actual redrawing takes place. In a graphical environment this can mean either minimizing the window or switching to a different virtual desktop, on the Linux virtual console just switch to another one ((<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +)<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*x*</kbd>).

Also notice that if you ran this over a slow network link (SSH over a GSM connection, for example), you would definitely see much less output before `cat` is killed by the signal, because the speed of the terminal redrawing wouldn't be the bottleneck any more.

Comment: If you're waiting on the data to come down a slow SSH pipe, you can use the OpenSSH escape sequence to close the connection. On a new line, type `~?` to see the available options (`~.` closes).

Comment: You also try stopping output with Ctrl+S which sends `tty-stop-output`. You can then send Ctrl+C. To resume output, press Ctrl+Q ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Tested that, didn't stop the flow of text for me on Ubuntu 14.04 + terminator + zsh.

Comment: @muru Thanks. I tried to test it, but wasn't able to reproduce the problem (my system is too fast, it would seem, or maybe I didn't try hard enough).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm afraid software flow control (which is Ctrl+S) won't help that much in this case (of a fast terminal link) - the data is already in the terminal buffer and waiting for the terminal to process it. Hence Ctrl+S will tell the application to stop sending *more* data, but what has already been sent will still have to be displayed.

Comment: @RJHunter sure, but you often don't want to kill the connection. Which is one of the many reasons terminal multiplexers are so useful especially over network connections.

Comment: just close the terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score 4):

#### Terminal Setup

I reckon this is more to do with the way the terminal is set up, than with any buffering issue. Check the output of `stty -a | grep intr`, you should have `intr = ^C;` on the output line if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is enabled at the `tty`/`pty`. If it isn't, you can use `stty intr ^C` to enable it. Add the line to your `.tcshrc` or `.login` to make it permanent (or delete the line that changes it in the first place!).

Failing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, you can also try sending `SIGQUIT` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>. If this doesn't work, again check `stty -a | grep quit` to see if it is properly set up.

#### Terminal Emulator Setup

Also check the settings for your terminal emulator (if you are using one), it may be that there is a shortcut set up at this level (maybe for copy or something) and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> does not reach the `pty` level. A shortcut could also be set up somewhere else in your desktop environment or Window system.

A good test on Linux if you are using a terminal emulator is to switch to a Linux console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>), login there and see if the same behaviour occurs. If it doesn't then this suggests the problem lies with your Window system or terminal emulator.

It could be an issue with the delay between data being read from the `pty` device as suggested by [peterph](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176925/48083). But if this is the case and you do actually have to wait minutes for the data to be displayed, then surely the terminal emulator is buffering *way* too much data (or your PC is very slow). The answer would be to find a way to reduce that buffer size in your terminal emulator settings or use a different one.

#### Extra Tip

Something else worth adding; I usually end up in the runaway `cat` situation when if I accidentally `cat` a binary file. The other effect of this can be to screw up your terminal settings (if the binary data happens to match various terminal escape codes which it often does). If `tput` is installed (usually is by default), you can avoid having to restart with the following command:

```
tput reset
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what `tmux` option `c0-change-interval` and `c0-change-trigger` designed for. You should use a screen manager for resumable session anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> option has been in Unix since the 110 baud days. Runaway cat commands were always a problem when a long ASCII file was dumped at the slow output device and the the entire file placed in the device driver output buffer.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> would start the flush of the buffer and a follow up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> would toggle off the flush so the cat could be read at normal speed. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> was entered and the entire file would flush and quickly return a command prompt.

Whether or not Linux device driver coders felt the need to continue to add this feature is unknown.  This feature was added at the device driver level where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> could only be implemented.  I used this to dump large debugging runs with lots of check print and then scroll down to the place I needed to see.

Comment: Ctrl-O doesn't seem to be implemented in modern Linuxes, at least not RHEL or Ubuntu server.

Answer (score -1):

open a new console, for example by clicking onto the console icon or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. There, enter

```
killall -9 cat
```

and cat will be killed unless you have a stale NFS lock or an "uninterruptible sleep" situation (read on a bad sector with no timeout set).

Comment: The problem is not with `cat`, it's about what `cat` has written to the terminal before dying and has not been read let alone processed or displayed by the terminal emulator yet (and is sitting in a (around 64kiB large on Linux) buffer inside the pty driver).

Comment: Then please try echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches which will drop a lot of buffers as well.

Comment: No, that would only drop cached data never things like that as that would affect functionality!

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk `drop_caches` controls pages used as cache by the kernel (usually for a file system), not internal buffers of terminals, network drivers and such - if it did, it would have quite grave consequences as Stéphane pointed out (basically you would lose data).

Comment: Wouldn't the `killall -9 cat` also kill any other cat instances that might still be doing good things in other process threads?

Answer (score -3):

When using bash, you can suspend the job using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then kill it, either using the PID or by following the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624691/linux-kill-background-task (e.g. kill -9 %%)

Comment: but I am using `tcsh` and Ctrl+Z is not working... already stated that in question.

Comment: yeah, sorry, didn't read in your post that you tried Ctrl+Z and I wrongly assumed that Ctrl+Z is handled by the shell in contrast to Ctrl+C which is handled by the application. That's why I thought Ctrl+Z worked instantly while Ctrl+C doesn't.

Answer (score -8):

**You can try with this**

Reset the display **use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>**

If cat is still running then open a new terminal and run this  `pkill -9 -f cat` " This will kill all cat processes. "

Comment: **Ctrl + J** doesn't work

Comment: pkill with '-f cat' is quite dangerous, since the -f will look for 'cat' pattern in whole command lines, which is likely to occur, and cause unwanted results...

Comment: For example, `pkill -f cat` on my desktop would kill the system tray area of Xfce4's taskbar.